# Online materials on Support Vector Machine

Tags: image-processing, algorithms

I am doing my final year project on Image Processing.I want to know about the Support Vector Machine.Please suggest some links for the former.

Thanks and regards in Advance

Comment: Questions for lists of resources are generally not welcome. [But see this proposal which might be applicable in this case, too.](http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1243/80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video Lectures : http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/117108048/

Notes : http://www.nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/106108057/ (Read from Lesson 25. These notes helped me very much)

Comment: The second link is the course plan material.I would be grateful if the proper link/material is posted.

Comment: It has the link to all chapters. If u still dont get, give me ur mail id, i will send it to u

Comment: .My mail id is adibuzz@rocketmail.com.Thanks.